# Term for lots of people going to the same place

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term for lots of people going to the same place?
For example:

> Our ___ consists of 14 hundred people and 14 hundred horses

Comment: A _group_ would be a more general term.

Comment: Nobody goes there anymore. It's too crowded.

Comment: *crowd*..........

Comment: A 'caravan', but I'd only use this in very rare circumstances. Historically, it was a group travelling together across certain deserts. A 'cavalcade' is a formal procession of people travelling on horses and/or in vehicles. Again, not an everyday word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use ***Procession*** depending on what sort of event it was.

> Our procession consisted of 1400 people, 14 horses, and a dog in a baby carriage.

-

> [***procession*** at Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/procession)
>   NOUN
>
> 1A number of people or vehicles moving forward in an orderly fashion, especially as part of a ceremony.
>
> *‘a funeral procession’*

You could also try words like "Mob", or "crowd" for less orderly groups but you'd need another word with them for moving

A ***Parade*** is another word

[second definition of Parade at Oxford living dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parade)

> 1.2 A series of people or things appearing or being displayed one after the other.
>
> ‘the parade of Hollywood celebrities who troop on to his show’